# Security for Mobile backend

Tags: android, ios, security, spring-security, mobile-application

We are developing a mobile app which will talk to a backend service hosted on Amazon ec2. One part of the app is registration. The registration data will be passed from the phone to the backend ec2 server as rest/JSON. The problem we have is how to make sure the registration request that we receive in the amazon(from the phone app) is from a valid app and not from spammers/hackers? I can't store any id, public key or something similar on the phone app as a clever person can easily decompile the code and get that logic. I am sure there would be some solution out side which others have implemented.

**Some solutions in my mind are: Some sort of Token Synchronisation/One time token etc.**

Please suggest some good solutions people out there have implemented.

Comment: you can use secure link like https

Comment: Thanks, We are anyway using https(Thats default). That doesn't solve the problem what I have described or is not meant for the issue I've mentioned.

Comment: if you use https then you have to use an certificate in your app. for security generate from keychain. I think this certificate is unique and any one can not get this